# 403 Forbidden error in Google Index API Using php

Tags: php, google-developers-console, google-search-console, google-indexing-api

I am trying to integrate google index API with my website in order to index my side but i am getting 401 error.
I searched and got this solution for my problem.
[Google Indexing API - 403 'Forbidden Response'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427054/google-indexing-api-403-forbidden-response)
But this is also not working in my case since i have verified that i am owner in google search console plus integrating right JSON authentication file.
I am checking index matrics but and getting all number of calls in my console platform.

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();

// service_account_file.json is the private key that you created for your service account.
$client->setAuthConfig('service_account_file.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing');

// Get a Guzzle HTTP Client
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$endpoint = 'https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish';

// Define contents here. The structure of the content is described in the next step.
$content = '{
  "url": "http://example.com/jobs/42",
  "type": "URL_UPDATED"
}';

$response = $httpClient->post($endpoint, [ 'body' => $content ]);
$status_code = $response->getStatusCode();
```

any help will be appreciated.
Thank in advance

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution to this? Facing the exact same issue right now.